# ActionHero js and custom websocket event

Tags: javascript, websocket, primus, actionhero

I am trying to use the websockets implementation of ActionHero.js. 
Looking at the documentation it's clear how to implement a chat, but I don't understand how is possible to emit a custom event from server to client and organizing a complex realtime app.
I am looking at the primus-emitter project examples: https://github.com/cayasso/primus-emitter

Anybody knows?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call `connection.send(message)` on the server.  In the client lib, the event `message` will be fired.  So, `client.on('message, function(m){ ... })`.

Be sure to add some descriptive content to the message you send from the sever (like perhaps `{"type": 'message type'}`) so you can route message types on the client.